# Post Request in Json format iOS

Tags: ios, json, ios7

I am new in iOS i have to send post request in `json` format. like,

```
  {"user":{"email":"abc@gmail.com"}}
```

My coding is like,

```
NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[postDict setValue:@"test@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];
//  [postDict setValue:text_password.text forKey:@"password"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:0 error:nil];
NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I am getting output

```
  {"email":"test@gmail.com"}
```

Please let me know how to add `{"user":`

Thank you.

Comment: Please explain your question properly

Comment: if you add user like email you can do the same thing... i mean you can add in postDict similar to email.

Comment: hello I have to send in this format {"user":{"email":"test@gmail.com"}} please let me know how to add {"user": before {"email":"test@gmail.com"}}

Comment: Create the dictionary with first object as user and pass its values as another dictionary of email.  try it and let me know.

Comment: hi i got vlaue  {"user":"{\"email\":\"test@clc.com\"}"} and unable to remove \ please let me know how to do this thanks

Comment: NSData *jsonDataa = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDictr options:0 error:nil];
    
   

    NSMutableDictionary *postDictr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    
    
    
    [postDictr setValue:stringData forKey:@"user"];

      NSString *stringDatae = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonDataa encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSLog(@"value we got %@",stringDatae)

Comment: Now you can fetch the data with the help of Keys... from response JSON you can get value with key User and the find value with email from user dictionary... try this

Comment: sorry i have not enough reputation

Comment: I have to post request in this format.so now I have to remove \ from string  {"user":"{\"email\":\"test@clc.com\"}"} plese let me know how to remove \ from string

Comment: why you want reputation. and try viral's answer.

Comment: sorry for that please let me know how to remove \

Comment: No need to remove it. because its added by system. and you are passing this JSON to web service so  no need to remove \. k

Comment: but backend will not accept this format

Comment: it will accept. you don't worry about it. you can pass it to your web service. and if you want to fetch this value. Try this..    postData is JSON Response Dictionary                                                                     NSDictionary *user1=[postDict valueForKey:@"user"];
 NSString *ss=[user1 valueForKey:@"email"];

Comment: and if still it is not solve your problem please let me know.

Comment: you have not replied

Comment: @Abhishek, Why are you changing accepted answer, once it solved and you thanked, is there serious need pf doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make One more Dictionary and pass first one dictionary into second you got your format

```
NSMutableDictionary *firstDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[data setValue:@"abc@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"]; NSMutableDictionary
*secondDic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];    
[userInfo setValue:firstDic forKey:@"user"];
```

Hope this is helpfull

Answer (score 0):

**1)  Post Data Using Default Function :-**

```
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict setValue:@"test@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];


        NSString *post =[dict JSONRepresentation];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        //NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:”YourURL”]]];

      //  [request setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                        initWithRequest:request
                                        delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
```

**2)  Post Data Using AFNetworking Library :-**

```
  NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setValue:@"test@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@“Your URL”]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *post =[dict JSONRepresentation];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)[postData length]];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //Add your request object to an AFHTTPRequestOperation
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

         NSString *response = [operation responseString];
         NSLog(@"response: %@",response);

     } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
     }];

    //call start on your request operation
    [operation start];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to enhance your mind to more dynamic way, because its very easy to do, but for your question, you can achieve it by code like this,

```
NSMutableDictionary *postDict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *dicEmail =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dicEmail setObject:@"abc@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];
[postDict setObject:dicEmail forKey:@"user"];
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict options:0 error:nil];
NSString *stringData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: Alwys welcome man !!, It is too easy, If you have tried little bit hard, may be solved it by your self. Anyway Enjoy !!

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want - {"user":{"email":"abc@gmail.com"}}
```

Then You need two dictionaries for this.

First one for the inner dictionary - {"email" : "abc@gmail.com"}. And

Second one for the outer dictionary - {"user" :{....}}

So first Create the inner dictionary.Such as-

```
NSMutableDictionary *data=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[data setValue:@"abc@gmail.com" forKey:@"email"];
```

Now create the outer dictionary.Such as-

```
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];   
[userInfo setValue:data forKey:@"user"];
```

And now create the JSON object-

```
NSData *JSONData=[[NSData alloc] init];
if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:userInfo])
{
    JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userInfo options:0 error:nil];
}
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"JSON Output: %@", jsonString);
```

And the output will be-
    {"user":{"email":"abc@gmail.com"}}

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Why are you initializing `NSData *JSONData=[[NSData alloc] init];` if you will  overwrite it with the serialized data after?

Comment: I just want to make it simple.Yes it is possible to make it in a single line.Like 
    NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userInfo options:0 error:nil];

If I make it in a single line inside the 'if' condition then there is no scope of the NSData object outside the 'if' condition.
Correct me if I wrong.Thank you. @FormigaNinja

Comment: You are correct about the scope stuff ... but I am trying to point that you are `alloc init` an instance of object, and overwriting it with the serialised data. I mean, you should not initialise it. (Just set `NSData *JSONData = nil;`)