# How to check JSON post return value

Tags: objective-c, json

I am new to JSON and I am trying to send a post I am wondering if how can I check if I did it properly or check the return value of it. Here's what I've done

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://json.myurl.com/.....];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"email", @"Email",
                     @"password", @"FirstName",
                        nil];
NSError *error;
NSData *postdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postdata];
```

Comment: Where's your code that submits the request?

Comment: NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self]; is it something like this?

Answer (score 0):

To check JSON POST return value:

```
NSString  *strUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://json.myurl.com/....."];

NSString *webStringURL = [strUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webStringURL];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];


NSDictionary *tmp = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"email", @"Email",
                     @"password", @"FirstName",
                     nil];

    NSError* error;
    NSData* postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmp options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error: &error];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc]init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *jsonData, NSError *error)
 {

     if (!error)
     {

         NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];


         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^
                        {

                            NSLog(@"jsonResponse--->%@",jsonResponse);

                        });
     }
     else
     {

         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^
                        {

                            NSLog(@"error--->%@",error.description);

                        });

     }


 }];
```

And to check you JSON format is correct or not go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887641/post-request-in-json-format-ios/29888854#29888854)

Comment: This example code works fine, but it is really inefficient and has unnecessary stuff inside.

Comment: As per as my knowledge this is one of the perfect way for JSON POST request. If you think it has any unnecessary stuff then please let me know and update me. :) @DaumantasVersockas

Comment: `dispatch_async` is completely unnecessary in this situation. You are not doing anything, that requires to make sure main thread usability. Manual encoding setup is doesn't required here also. Do you really need to setup content length here? Also, code could be written in a prettier manner. For example, why to write `if (error == nil)` if you can write `if (!error)` or even more simple, `if (error) {} else {}`. Request itself works correctly, though. Sorry for critics, it is just my personal opinion. Peace! :)

Comment: Now it's looking good according to you ;)  @DaumantasVersockas

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner, I would recommend using third party framework, widely used by iOS developers across the world, called `AFNetworking`.

By using `AFNetworking`, HTTP requests are simple as that:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

[manager POST:url parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    // TODO: Parse success here!
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    // TODO: Parse failure here!
}];
```

In given example, object `responseObject` is a representation of API response JSON object.

Installation and further usage instructions of `AFNetworking` can be found in their [website](http://afnetworking.com).